# Unable to go get from private Gitlab repository

Tags: go, gitlab, go-modules

I want to use `go get` to get a package located in a private GitLab repository. My go version is `go1.15.4 darwin/amd64`. And the current directory has a `go.mod` file.

When I run `go get -v git.xxx.com/path-to/package@v0.0.3`, It shows

```
get "git.xxx.com/path-to/package": found meta tag get.metaImport{Prefix:"git.xxx.com/path-to/package", VCS:"git", RepoRoot:"https://git.xxx.com/path-to/package.git"} at //git.xxx.com/path-to/package?go-get=1
get "git.xxx.com/path-to": found meta tag get.metaImport{Prefix:"git.xxx.com/path-to", VCS:"git", RepoRoot:"https://git.xxx.com/path-to.git"} at //git.xxx.com/path-to?go-get=1
Enter passphrase for key '~/.ssh/id_rsa':
```

And after I input my password it hangs for hours without showing anything.

I also tried-

```
$ sudo go get git.xxx.com/path-to/package@v0.0.3

go get git.xxx.com/path-to/package@v0.0.3: git.xxx.com/path-to/package@v0.0.3: invalid version: unknown revision v0.0.3
```

But the repository indeed has a tag v0.0.3. And If I try without version-

```
$ sudo go get git.xxx.com/path-to/package

go get git.xxx.com/path-to/package: module git.xxx.com/path-to/package: git ls-remote -q origin in ~/go/pkg/mod/cache/vcs/bcb4baa8ab83c8bb452456922f12d22e1981b76bd2649d163d0c53c6: exit status 128:
    gitlab@git.xxx.com: Permission denied (publickey).
    fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
    
    Please make sure you have the correct access rights
    and the repository exists.
```

But I can clone this repository. So I have access rights and have this in `~/.gitconfig` file

```
[url "ssh://gitlab@git.xxx.com:2222/"]
    insteadOf = https://git.xxx.com/
```

Note that, everything was okay in my system (I could use `go get`) until I ran this command `go clean -cache -modcache -i -r` following [this blog](https://lecstor.com/go-clear-cache/).

Answer (score 0):

I am wondering why the port in the git config?, maybe is not the root cause but you can try

```
[url "git@gitlab.com:"]
    insteadOf = https://gitlab.com/
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's assume that you already set `.git config` `sshd_config` correctly.
You can try

```
cd $HOME # out of gopath
env GO111MODULE=off go get git.xxx.com/path-to/package
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try use GOPRIVATe evn variable
https://golang.org/cmd/go/#hdr-Module_configuration_for_non_public_modules